# jQuery custom event, interrupt function on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I am trying to create an event (see code below). In  my example I have 2 events that are fired one before clearing a div and one after its text is updated.

My question is how can I stop function from proceeding further by using `return false;` on clear event. Is it possible to interrupt `_test()` function on event ?

**JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/3tTQy/

```
<div id="test">MANGO</div>

var _test = function (text) {
    var div = $("#test");
    div.trigger({
        type: "Clear",
        text: text
    });
    div.empty();
    //SOME OTHER PROCESSES
    div.trigger({
        type: "Update",
        text: text
    });
    div.html(text);
};
_test("sdfds");
$("#test").on('Clear', function (e) {
    console.log("Clearing");
    return false;  
});
```

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded, there are no interrupts.

Comment: so there is no way i can stop function from proceedng further by  adding something in On.event ? right ?

Comment: Right. I don't think the handler even runs immediately when you call `trigger`. The event is added to the event queue, and when the JS returns to the main event loop it gets processed.

Comment: Barmar is right. It's single threaded. It will process trigger synchronously, run handler fully, and then go back and run the rest of the function. Just like it would be a function call. If you have some long job to do in JS and it should be stopped on some event / end of other processing then chop it (both) into smaller pieces that would fit for running in intervals (setInterval) or with some pauses (setTimeout for next piece). Then you can cancel interval or timeout on some event (like finishing update cancels clear or vice versa).